# Flutter WEB - Close WebView (url_laucher)

Tags: flutter, dart

Using url_launch to open Webview (LOGIN). How can I identify that the WebView has been closed? How to get the token generated in your URL(WebView)?

I need to do this in Flutter Web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  webview_flutter lib to open Webview to find closed and get data from this lib.

```
 import 'dart:io';

 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
 }

 class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     // Enable virtual display.
     if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).